# Use Entity less Repositories in service in Symfony

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.2

Is there any way in symfony that "Entity less repositories" be used in services just like one service is calling another service.

I am asking because I want put sql DQL/SQL in methods separated from Services like in 2 layers as I don't want to map any table with entity.

> **Services         >>               Repositories        >>             Db**
>
> **Twitter Service         >>        TwitterRepository        >>    Table1, tabl2, tabl3, table4, tabl5         Db**

for example I can replace Twitter in following call

```
$data = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository->("MyApiBundle:SocialMedia\Twitter")->findProfileTweets($profileId)
```

in short 
1. Repository can be called in service.
2. Entity should not be used.

any help we be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you still want to use the Doctrine repository class?  If so then define it as a service and inject it.

Comment: @Cerad, Can you please suggest how to define it in service.yml and how to inject it in service. as I guess entity name still required in service.yml

Comment: The accepted answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415177/how-can-i-add-get-container-in-form-builder-symfony Still not clear if this is actually what you want.