# How Can I add get container in form builder symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

How Can I add get container in form builder symfony ?

I would like use $get->container in form builder...

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting the whole container into a form type is a bad practice. Please consider injecting only required dependencies to your form type. You can simply [define your form type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html) and inject required dependencies.

src/AppBundle/Form/TaskType.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
// ...

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // ...
}
```

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    AppBundle\Form\TaskType:
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags: [form.type]
```

---

To inject a repository class there are two ways. The second approach is more clean.

Inject an EntityManager class and get repository class from EM:

```
$this->em->getRepository(User::class)
```

Register repository class as a service using EM factory and inject it to your form type:

```
  services:
    AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository:
      factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
      arguments: ['AppBundle\Entity\User']
```

Comment: I would like get repository from my app

Comment: Updated my answer with the good practice to inject a Repository class in your service.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is to pass container as parameter to your FormType file from the controller:

```
$form_type = new MyFormType($this->container);
```

And add a construct method in your FormType file:

```
protected $container;

public function __construct($container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Then you can access to container by: '$this->container';

Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Only if they are using an ancient version of Symfony.  Times have changed.